# How can I do a LINQ to read XML file

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to read a XML file, but I want to know just the name of the `node` and her value.

**Example**

```
<User>
    <Contact>
        <Name>Lucas</Name>
        <ID>123</ID>
    </Contact>
</User>
```

I'm trying use this code below but without success. How can I return just the `node` name and her value ?

```
foreach (var name in doc2.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XNode>().Select(x => x).Distinct())
{
    string nome = name.ToString();
}
```

I want that my string receives the name of my Node, is this case will be `Name` and her value, that will be `Lucas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var element in doc2.Root.Descendants()) {
    String name = element.Name.LocalName;
    String value = element.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated my question with the XML, and how can I exclude my `<Contact>` tag in this solution ?